# Amazon ec2 java application returns HTTP Status 405

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, log4j

I'm new to Amazon aws. 
I've installed a new application using eclipse toolkit and running it on server does everything good except that when the browser open it returns a HTTP STATUS 405.

I think it might be due to the log4j configuration as I've found in logs the last line was a warning mentioning the log4j configuration.

Kindly guide me through this.

Comment: What call are you trying to make? maybe you are trying to GET a method which is implemented as POST?

Comment: This is a sample test application. Nothing much.
It just displays a web page Saying hello

Comment: provide more specific errors and the configuration that you have in your application.